# How do you show that $\vec{p}$ is unique if $A\vec{p} = \vec{b}$, where $\vec{p}$ is in Row $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is an $m$ x $n$ matrix, and $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ is consistent, where $\vec{x} = \vec{p} + \vec{u}$, where $\vec{p}$ is in Row $A$ and $\vec{u}$ is in Nul $A$, how do you show that there is a unique $\vec{p}$ such that $A\vec{p} = \vec{b}$?

The hint given was to look at the equations $\vec{p} = \vec{p_1} + (\vec{p} - \vec{p_1})$ and $\vec{p} = \vec{p} + \vec{0}$, where $A\vec{p} = A\vec{p_1} = \vec{b}$. I have tried working from both of these equations, but see no way to show that $\vec{p} = \vec{p_1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x_1=p_1 + u_1$ and $x_2=p_2 + u_2$ where the $p_{i}$'s are in the row space of $A$ and the $u_{i}$'s are in the null space of $A$.  (Both $x_{i}$ satisfy $Ax_{i}=b$.  The goal is to show that $p_1=p_2$.

Look at $p_1-p_2$.  It is in the row space of $A$ because the row space is a subspace and subspaces are closed.  Also,

$$A(p_1-p_2)=Ap_1 - Ap_2 = b - b = 0$$
implying that either $p_1-p_2=0$ or that $p_1-p_2$ is in the null space.  We know that $p_1-p_2$ is in the row space of $A$ (not the null space).  This means that $p_1-p_2=0$ or that $p_1=p_2$.